# htaccess url rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using following htaccess url rewrite rule for optional query strings...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)?$ post.php?state=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ post.php?state=$1&zone=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ post.php?state=$1&zone=$2&region=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ post.php?state=$1&zone=$2&region=$3&sub_region=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ post.php?state=$1&zone=$2&region=$3&sub_region=$4&suburb=$5 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ post.php?state=$1&zone=$2&region=$3&sub_region=$4&suburb=$5&postcode=$6 [NC,L]
```

Its too slow, can you please suggest better approach to achieve the same. thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's the rules that is making is slow?

Comment: @JonLin yes is this right the approach for the same?

Comment: I have hundreds of rules like that and the response times makes no difference if I have 1 or over 100.